# How to fix Inherited Hidden NavigationIOS (only show navbar when desired) - React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, navigation, react-native

It seems that when I start off my app in index.ios.js that I really only have two options: hide the navigationios component from the start when routing to other views or have it show in all my views.

Is there any way to make it transparent when I desire? Here is my code on index.ios.js:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Login = require('./App/Components/loginPage');

var { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, NavigatorIOS, StatusBarIOS } = React;

class nomsyRN extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          component: Login,
          title: 'Home',
        }}
        navigationBarHidden={true}
        tintColor="#FFFFFF"
        barTintColor="transparent"
        titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
      />
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 0,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    height: 100,
    width: 400,
  },
  buttoncontainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('nomsyRN', () => nomsyRN);
```

This enables me to avoid having a shown navbar on the login page that this page routes to, and on all transition pages. But once the user gets into the app, having the navbar becomes necessary for orientation - but since the initial navigationios component hides the navbar - all subsequent pages inherit this trait. Is there any way around this problem?

I'm a novice so I greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check out [React Native Router Flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux). We just switched to it last week and we've loved it so far. It allows you to specify your routes up front in your index.ios.js file as well as specify which routes you should or shouldn't hide the navbar in.

Comment: I'll check it out - thanks! Also, thank you again because I used your egghead tutorial to get started - so your kind of my web mentor in a way lol

Comment: Also - Are there any nav modules you reccomend in terms of being able to more easily customize the navbar?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I'm glad you enjoyed the series. And yup, take a look at this one, https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-navbar. I use both <-- and the React Native Router Flux and I've really enjoyed both of them.

Comment: One more thing (sorry for all the questions) have you tried https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router ? Only ask because, seeing how the router flux employs react-native-navbar, I'd like to use this module in the same way if possible

Comment: Yup. We actually went with that one before switching to RNRF. It led to frustration with having to pass around this.props.toRoute everywhere we wanted a route change. I also had to fork it because the author hasn't been too active with it.